# 90/180/270 deg rotation of BitmapImage in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have followed the [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.rotation(v=vs.110).aspx#feedback) for this

But the problem is at TrasformedBitmap.
The error says that

> The type or namespace name 'TransformedBitmap' could not be found

I am not getting why this error pops up because I have included the namespace i.e `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` and `PresentationCore assembly` is also there.

Comment: can we see the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Transformed Bitmap is deprecated you can now try setting a BitmapImage to an Image control and rotate that image using

```
MyImageControl.Source= new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/SmallLogo.scale-240.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

RotateTransform myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
myRotateTransform.Angle=30;
MyImageControl.RenderTransform = myRotateTransform;
```

[image: proof of it rotating on center axis]

Comment: rotation is working now. but image goes out of the expected boundary of image control

Comment: i want to rotate image keeping center at fixed position and with this code image rotates with topmost left corner fixed

Comment: unless you have set the centre point of the image it will take the centre point of original image as default and rotate it using it not the topmost left but centre.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in which I was using the default logo image and rotating it at an angle of 30 and it rotates using the centre axis of image not the topmost left